# Class retains previous content where new instance is expected

Tags: python

I define a class, and a function which creates an instance of that class. I thought this function should create a new instance every time. However, it looks like it "inherits" its content from last call. Anyone can explain this? Thanks!

```
class test:
    a = []
    def b(self,x):
        self.a.append(x)

def add():
    t = test()
    t.b(2)
    return t

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print add().a
    print add().a
    print add().a
```

Output:

```
[2]
[2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Can anyone explain why and/or how the add function is being called with .a?  I will create a new question if you'd prefer me not to ask here.

Comment: Hi Jake, add function returns an instance of the "test" class. And 'a' is a class variable. add().a = (add()).a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how the definition of the `a` instance variable should look:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = []
```

The way it was before `a` was not declared as an instance variable, but a class variable that was being shared across all instances of the class.

Answer (score 3):

You defined `a` as a *class* variable. It's not bound to an instance of your class, but to the class itself, so there's only one list that's "shared" across the instances of the class.

You need to make it an instance variable:

```
class test:
    def b(self, x):
        self.a = []
        self.a.append(x)
```

Also, you should inherit from `object` in order to utilize new-style classes:

```
class test(object):
```