# Dot operator on user defined python functions

Tags: python

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227090/class-retains-previous-content-where-new-instance-is-expected#17227090) thread a few days ago, and I understand(after reading the answers) why the OP was getting the behavior in question, but I do not understand what is happening with the dot operator being used on the "add" function: `print add().a`.  `a` is an element of class `test`, and  `add` creates an instance of `test`, but how is `a` being accessed right on the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that post, the function `add()` returns a `test` object. That object has an attribute `a`, so it can be accessed using the `.` operator.

In other words, `add().a` accesses the attribute `a` of the *result*  of the function call to  `add`, not of the function object itself (that would be `add.a`).

Comment: @JakeSellers: I'm not sure I understand. `.a` is applied to whatever `add()` `return`s, regardless of how many other things it does.

Answer (score 2):

`add()` this creates an object, it is not assigned to a name (perhaps that's the confusion), then `.a` acesses the member of the (unnamed) `add()` object.

`print` simply does what it needs to do.

It is almost the same as doing this:

```
foo = add()
print foo.a
del(foo)
```